# Python - Printing a latex string to the console

Tags: python, latex

Morning,

I would like to print a latex string, or at least a latex symbol to my console window in Python something like:

```
print('Percentage of points within $\pm$ 8% = {:.2f}%'.format(percent_in_region))
```

At the minute I just want the plus-minus symbol, but I can see that knowing how to do this would be useful in the longer term too.

Is someone able to help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print a plus-minus symbol you can do:

```
print(chr(177))
```

which will print the unicode character 177 which is the plus-minus symbol.

Comment: Thanks, not quite what I was looking for, but definitely a way ahead for now